# Increment in firestore is adding long floats to firestore field?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a metrics function from my client-side. However, the increment operation is adding long floating-point numbers to a Firestore field, even though I have fixed my value to two decimal places. It seems that Firestore is still storing long floating-point values.

```js
const verdict = Number((actionData - afterActionData).toFixed(2));

const payload = {
[todayDate]: {
[dataKey()]: increment(+verdict)
};

await updateDoc(fireStoreMetricsDoc, payload);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's always going to happen on floating point numbers. They sacrifice precision in order to be able to store a larger range of numbers in their allocated space.

You have a few options:

- Round the number to the right number of digits when you display it.
- Store the fixed point number as a string, i.e. `"3.04"`, as Firestore doesn't support fixed point numbers (very few systems do). But you'd lose the ability to do math through the `increment` operator in that case.
- Store them as full values - i.e. if this'd be a currency, store it as cents so that it becomes `304`. This is actually the most common way to store fixed point numbers.

Also see:

- [Fixed point vs Floating point number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524838/fixed-point-vs-floating-point-number)
- [Firestore increment floating points issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525322/firestore-increment-floating-points-issue)
- [FieldValue.increment produce the wrong sum when using decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75636639/fieldvalue-increment-produce-the-wrong-sum-when-using-decimals)